# Another site in the sub-directory of angular site

Tags: angular, hosting, netlify, angular-universal

I have an angular site that is being prerendered using angular universal and hosted on netlify.

I am creating a directory called second-site in the output folder of my first site and keeping the second site's build output's in that folder

When I directly open the mysite.com/second-site/ in a new window I am being served my second site correctly

but when I try to navigate to it from the first site angular routing is taking over and showing the wild card route if configured or just a blank screen if no wildcard route is configured.

So how should I configure this so that my second site is shown and the the angular 404